# Connect netbeans to online database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector, database-connection

I have got an error when I try to connect netbeans to an on-line MySql database:

> Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:mysql://qatarmonk.uk:3306/qatarmon_k?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
>   using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (null,  message from server: "Host
>   'cpc19-brad19-2-0-cust137.17-1.cable.virginm.net' is not allowed to
>   connect to this MySQL server")

Please, how can I solve the problem?
Best regards.

Comment: You need to contact the administrator of this system. He will need to whitelist your IP (although you probably have a dynamic IP, which means it is not a good solution); I'd also question the wisdom of connecting to a database over the internet.

Comment: I am creating a software that will be used by few users over the internet. Also, I am student at the university and from home I am trying to connect my application to the internet database since the university database works only within the campus network!

Comment: Thank You very much Mark. I made whit list and it is working fine. Thank you very much